# Show time span in asp.net likes facebook

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have content database with posted time !
I found some date time format in C#(short Date String,long Date String,...)

But I want to show my time span in my asp.net page likes
2 days ago , 3 days ago , 25 minutes ago (Just likes face book)

Comment: What have you tried?  What language are you using? You can't expect people to do your work for you.  You have to show that you have tried something

Comment: where actually are you stuck??? Your question says nothing. Please elaborate a little.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following jQuery plugins were made for exactly that purpose:

- [CuteTime jQuery](http://tpgblog.com/cutetime/)
- [timeago](http://timeago.yarp.com/)

Using a client side solution like CuteTime will

- allow you to update the texts without refreshing the page from the server, and
- allow you to use output caching while still getting accurate timing info.

Comment: Cool. I've updated the answer with another option.

Answer (score 0):

I would create an extension method on a timespan that returns an enum item or string

I'm not going to write the code for you as you haven't actually given us any of your code to look at / correct.